# $X\sim\mathcal{E}xp(2)$ and $Y\sim N(6,7)$, where $7=\sqrt{DY}$. Let $cov(X,Y)=-0.7$. What is $\rho(4X,Y+3)$?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

Let $X\sim\mathcal{E}xp(2)$ and $Y\sim N(6,7)$, where $7$ is the standard deviation of $Y$. Let $cov(X,Y)=-0.7$. How do I find the correlation $\rho(4X,Y+3)$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By definition,
\begin{equation*}
Cov(aX,Y+b) = a Cov(X,Y)
\end{equation*}
As $X\sim Expo(2)$, $Var(4X)=16\left(\dfrac{1}{4}\right)=4$ and since $Y\sim N(6,7^2)$,  $Var(Y+3)=7^2$.
Given that $Cov(X,Y)=-0.7$. Hence, by the definition of correlation coefficient, we have,
\begin{eqnarray*}
\rho(4X,Y+3)&=& \dfrac{Cov(4X,Y+3)}{\sqrt{Var(4X)}\sqrt{Var(Y+3)}}=\dfrac{4\times -0.7}{2\times 7}=-0.2
\end{eqnarray*}

Answer (score 1):

\begin{align}
\rho(4X, Y+3) &= \rho (X, Y+3) \\
&= \rho(X, Y)
\end{align}

Can you take it from here?